# Padding is not working in horizontal line css html

Tags: html, css

I want to add padding in my hr,

```
hr {
  padding-left: 200px;
  
}
```

but it's not working. how to add padding in my hr ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Padding does not work in `hr`.

You have to use `margin` instead:

```
hr {

margin-left: 200px;

}
```

And it'll work.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the quick response

Comment: @user19136007 please accept my answer if you find it correct. It is the tick in my answer.

Comment: Ok I will do that

Comment: Padding works for hr. But browser can't display it properly until you change the width of your hr. Also padding and margin is two different things. Op want to add a padding not a margin.

Comment: @VishalKalansooriya he also never said he wanted to change the width so margin seems to be the best way

Comment: @Cédric He said that "I want to add padding in my hr" not margin. These are two different things

Comment: @VishalKalansooriya Yes indeed but sometimes you want to achieve something in a certain way but it is not how you should. If he absolutely needs padding for some reason you answer is the best, but if he needs a space on the left, Python's answer is the best (because it doesn't set the width). **both of your answers are usefull**. From how he asked, *my guess* is that `margin` **seems to be** a better solution.

Comment: @Cédric My problem is with this. "Padding does not work in hr." Also if he doesn't know about the width of the hr, he can simply set it via width: calc(100% - padding's size) or just something like that

Answer (score 2):

Before adding padding, you should have to set a width for your `hr` otherwise it will display in full width.

```css
hr:first-of-type{
    width: 100px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
hr:last-of-type{
    width: 100px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<hr>
<hr>
```

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 1):

HR is slightly different from most HTML tags in its defined behaviour, as it tries to fill up the whole width of the containing element.

The only way I know to stop it expanding over any margins is to explicitly set a *width* attribute

```
hr {
  width: 90%;
  padding-left: 200px;
}
```

Even then, it seems to ignore the padding, so you should use a margin instead:

```
hr {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

It's still kind of scrappy and imprecise. If the ruled line needs to be in line with some other element, you're probably best ensuring that they are in the same DIV, so that the ruled line can start at the left margin of the div.

Answer (score 0):

As Python mentioned, padding does not work with `hr`

A good solution would be to place the `hr` inside a `div`

Another workaround (not recommended, more like a band-aid) would be to create a `div` and apply styling to it to create a line, particularly add a single border to it

For example,

```html
<div class="divider"></div>
```

And for the styling

```css
.divider {
  border-top: 1px solid #081521; /* Create the border, i.e. Divider */
  margin: 1rem auto; /* Add a Margin and Center the divider */
}
```